# Face API in microsoft cognitive service

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services

How to send binary data in face detect api

https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect

when I am sending binary data it is giving below error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidImage",
    "message": "Decoding error, image format unsupported."
  }
}
```

Thanks,
Saroj

Comment: What image are you trying to upload? Which format does it use? have you tried other images or formats?

Comment: there is two options one is u can pass the url of the image and another is binary data.  the url is working correct but when I am passing the binary data it is giving error

Comment: Could you please show us how you're converting the image to an octed-stream? Could you also provide a sample image you're testing?

Bear in mind that we have no context here; we need as much relevant information as you can provide to help you with your problem.

Comment: http://textuploader.com/drsq8

Comment: find the image format from the above link

Comment: the request body i am sending like {"url":" converted image"}

Comment: You're sending an `application/json` request with a base64 encoded image (as a string) instead of a `application/octet-stream` with the binary bytes of the image, as specified by the [API documentation](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236).

Comment: I am sending header as application/octet-stream and binary data still giving same error

Comment: Try following [this official tutorial](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/face-api/documentation/face-api-how-to-topics/howtodetectfacesinimage#step2), using the [C# official SDK for Face API](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-face-windows).

Comment: Face API already provide several SDKs for Windows(C#), iOS(Obj-c), Andoird(java) and Python, please have a try on these SDKs for avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: Thanks the issue is solved.  for me json data works..

Comment: @SarojJena could you post the correct answer to this question so that if anyone else faces a similar issue they can benefit?

Answer (score 0):

```
String AzureURL = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect";
String FaceID = "";

var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", SubscriotionKey);
string queryString = "returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=false&returnFaceAttributes=age,gender";

queryString = "returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=false";
string uri = AzureURL + "?" + queryString;

HttpResponseMessage response;
string JSONString;


using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(ImageBytes))
{
      content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
      response = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;
      JSONString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

      JSONString = JSONString.Replace("[", "");
      JSONString = JSONString.Replace("]", "");

      var definition = new { faceId = "" };
      var FaceGUID = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(JSONString, definition);

      if(JSONString != "")
          FaceID = FaceGUID.faceId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can upload an image as bytes. According to the documentation, 
the body of the POST to add a face image only takes a URL. 
https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039523b